# In JQuery plugin for facebook login, some function cannot be called

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-plugins, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to code a jQuery Plugin for facebook login, but some function cannot be called in plugin. plugin code as below:

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        facebookLogin: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.append('<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>');

                function statusChangeCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

                // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
                // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
                // code below.
                function checkLoginState() {
                    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                        statusChangeCallback(response);
                    });
                }

                window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: 'xxxxxxxx',
                        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
                        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                        version: 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
                    });
                };

                // Load the SDK asynchronously
                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id))
                        return;
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

When I click the '**Log In**' button, the function **checkLoginState()** defined in plugin cannot be called. And I want to keep **checkLoginState()** in **facebookLogin()**, because I want to pass some parameters into functions, how can I solve it?

Comment: Making it jQuery plugin is wrong. `onlogin="checkLoginState()` used liked this `checkLoginState` needs to be global function.

Comment: Alternative: Don’t use the Login Button plugin - but your own button, and call FB.login on click. That way, you can specify the callback function for FB.login any way you like.

Comment: Yes, I got your meaning, **checkLoginState()** called outside of jQuery plugin, So **checkLoginState()** cannot be found. Do you have any good solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) & [cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe), I 've solve it under your assistance. The following tag provided by facebook is not necessary.

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

You can define it by yourself, then you can bind jQuery event on that. And functions defined in jQuery Plugin can be called. Besides, **FB.getlogin** would be used instead of **FB.getLoginStatus**

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        facebookLogin: function () {
            return this.each(function () {

                $(this).append('<span id="facebook-login" class="icon-facebook2"></span>');

                $("#facebook-login").on("click", function () {
                    checkLoginState();
                });

                function statusChangeCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

                // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
                // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
                // code below.
                function checkLoginState() {
                    FB.login(function (response) {
                        // handle the response
                        statusChangeCallback(response);
                    }, {
                        scope: 'public_profile,email',
                        return_scopes: true
                    });
                }

                window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: 'xxxxxxxx',
                        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
                        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                        version: 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
                    });
                };

                // Load the SDK asynchronously
                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id))
                        return;
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```